# JBoss ManagedThreadFactory

Tags: java, jboss, mdc

I am trying to override the default JBoss 7.3 ManagedThreadFactory through the standalone.xml with my custom factory so to inject on each thread a specific context (shared MDC).

Is this even possible?

So far I'm struggling and I have found only examples where a new custom ManagedThreadFactory is registered and used directly in the application, but don't seem to be able to completely override the default behavior.

Comment: It's likely a bug that. There needs to be context propagation which copies MDC to the new thread. In Jakarta EE 10, JBoss EAP 8 will implement this, will have a way to do this as it was added to the concurrency API.